# Comparing Non-Converged Results of Monte-Carlo Integration

Tags: hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo, equivalence, integral

I would like to know which would be the "best" way to compare the results of
two different Monte Carlo integration schemes at a non-converged state,
and check if they actually compute (converge to) the same value.

In particular, I can compute an arbitrary (within reasonable limits) number of samples of the "reference" integrator,
and an arbitrary (preferably low) number of samples of the "test" integrator.
Now I would like to be able to check / state that the expected values of both integrators are equal (or not).

My current approach would be to bootstrap differences between the samples of both integrators
and to test those deltas for equivalence ($\mu = 0$) via a one sample TOST.

However, I am a little bit unsure if this is the proper way to do it, due to the [controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Criticism) around hypothesis testing.
And since I am relatively free to pre-compute whatever quantity / statistic for the reference integrator,
I have a hunch that maybe some Bayesian approach would be better.

Any suggestions, recommendations and corrections are appreciated.